# Is CVE-2022-22963 and CVE-2022-22965 affecting Azure cloud services?

Tags: azure

CVE-2022-22965/Spring4Shell (Spring Core) and CVE-2022-22963 (Spring Cloud Functions) vulnerabilities were recently discovered. Was Azure cloud Services affected by this?

Could you please let us know if you want us to look into this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look out for blog posts from the Microsoft Threat Intelligence team here: https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/microsoft-security-intelligence

There's one for CVE-2022-22965: https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2022/04/04/springshell-rce-vulnerability-guidance-for-protecting-against-and-detecting-cve-2022-22965/